# How to get Two Unique ID from single Device

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, uuid

Is there any other UniqueID that I can access other than `UUID`? I want two UniqueID for my app. One that I'm using is `UUID` how can I get another Unique number from the device.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would require such a thing but even though `UUID` is the only unique id within a device you can still get user's notification token. Which is again a unique value for that device.

A better solution would be to register the device with an API call to your server and there you can insert/update the device info to your DB thus you'll have 2 unique ids for the same device: `UUID` and DB entry id.